angular v18 monorepo with capacitor
I have an angular v18 monorepo wtih some projects like bamm, boom, plong. If i ng build them, they are going to the folder dist and every project have its subfolder called dist/bamm, dist/boom and dist/plong. So far so good.
I have installed capacitor and added android. If I npx cap copy android, it copies what is it CapacitorConfig specified. If I change webdir, than ( I am not sure) copies all to the same existing folder android. If I npx cap open android than it looks messie because I need to overlook gradle and webmanifest, also png from former npx cap copy android I found.
So my question is: How can I make that like ng build, that npx cap copy to differnet folders and npx cap open android uses this folders like for example npx cap copy android --bamm and npx open android -boomm.
